# Spring controller can accept ZonedDatedTime as @RequestParam but not @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

The following code works

```
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> test(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime startDate,
                                       @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime endDate) {

    return null;
}
```

with this request

```
https://localhost:8080/api/v1/test?startDate=2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-00:00&endDate=2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-00:00
```

But the following code throws exception

```
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> test(@RequestBody @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime startDate,
                                       @RequestBody @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime endDate) {

    return null;
}
```

with this body

```
 {
    "endDate":"2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-00:00",
    "startDate":"2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-00:00"    
}
```

has this exception

```
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.ZonedDateTime value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.ZonedDateTime value
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `@ModelAttribute` or make object or map for mapping body, because Reflection utils not have opportunity for reading function parameter names (you cant specify property name for mapping).

```java
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String occupation;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RestController
public class MyController {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping(value="/myfoo")
    public void process2(@ModelAttribute("email") String email) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping(value="/vals")
    public void process(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> values) {
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping(value="/user", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void process2(@RequestBody User user) {
    }
}
```

**ATTENTION**
always set name of property for `@RequestParam`, else you can take error if somebody add not only this parameter or changed function signature